# Send input value in WScript.Shell inside HTA application

Tags: javascript, html, wscript.shell

I'm trying to make a restart application that takes seconds from the HTML input button and sends it to JS function which contains `WScript.Shell`.

```
<script>
function languages(){
  var test = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

  var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var path = "shutdown -r -t " & test;
  shell.run(path,1,false);
}
</script>
```

```
<div align="center">
  <img src="restartICO.png" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input id="myInput" type="number" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button class="blokirebaARA2" onclick="languages();"
    title="შლის ენებს და ამატებს ხელახლა GE & RUS">GE-RUS</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

I don't know how to pass variable correctly in htis format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you send variables inside HTA application:

```
function restart(){
  var testr = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  if (testr == "") {
  var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var path = "shutdown -r -f -t 0";
  shell.run(path,1,false);
  }
  else {
  var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
  var path = "shutdown -r -f -t " + testr;
  shell.run(path,1,false);
  }
}
```

var path = "shutdown -r -f -t " + **testr**